# Evaluation of the integral $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\mbox{If}\ n>1,\ \mbox{then prove that}\quad\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm{d}x \over
\left(x + \,\sqrt{\, x^{2} + 1\,}\,\right)^{n}} = {n \over n^{2} - 1}
$$

Could someone give me little hint so that I could proceed in this question. I tried putting $x = \tan\left(A\right)$ but it did not work out.

Answer (score 5):

> *Could someone give me little hint so that I could proceed in this question.*

**Hint**. One may perform the change of variable
$$
x \in [0,\infty),\quad x=\sinh u \implies x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=e^u, \quad dx=\cosh u\:du,
$$ giving
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^n}=\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-nu}\cosh u\:du.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: [+1] Supplementary hint : If you know Laplace Transform, you have an immediate result...

Answer (score 4):

**Claim:**
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^n}=\frac{n}{n^2-1}$$
**Proof:**

- Let $x=\sinh\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp\theta-\exp(-\theta)\right)$.
- Then

  - $dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp\theta+\exp(-\theta)\right)d\theta$, and
  - $(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=\exp\theta$, so we have

$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^n}=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{2}\left(\exp\theta+\exp(-\theta)\right)\cdot \exp(-n\theta)d\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\left[\exp(-(n-1)\theta+\exp(-(1+n)\theta)\right]d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right]=\frac{n}{n^2-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a hint, so here is one:

Let
$$
u=x+\sqrt{1+x^2}.
$$

Comment: Why do someone want to delete my answer? The hint is really serious. It transforms the integral into the easiest possible. Please explain yourself!